# Is there a way to assign tasks from a project into a different project's iteration?

Tags: azure-devops

I have the problem whereby we have lots of projects. 1 for each client.

We have 1 project set up to represent a specific team's work load (bugs from the other projects)... it gathers tickets and tasks from the aforementioned projects via queries.

This has been fine... but i would now like to start creating sprints for the tasks that are coming from other projects.

I have tried to create tasks that have url references to the original tickets. this means i can utilise estimates and capacity... but it's a faff re-creating the items essentially.

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to calculate the remaing work from a Task work item in a different project.

The workaround id **copy the Task and move the copied Task work item to the project and iteration**. Details as below:

#### 1. Copy the Task from a different project to the project you are working

Open the Task from the different project -> `...` button -> Create copy of work item -> select your current project -> select Include existing links -> OK.

[image]

[image]

#### 2. Specify related fields for the copied Task work item

The new copied Task work item will be opened, in the window, specify the iteration and remaining work for the Task -> Assign To the Task to the user -> Save & Close.

Then, in the project iteration you are working for, you can see the copied Task work item's remaining work is added for the user in the iteration.

Comment: This is not ideal, but thank you. Do you know if this will change in any future iterations of vsts?